YA novel about a male character who discovers he is the son of Lucifer/Satan
This wasn't my question at first, but I'm intrigued about the series, so I'm asking for this person and myself.
There are at least 5 books in the series, and the 5th one was released in 2018. There may be more, but this person wasn't sure.
So the plot points that were remembered was a male teenager who realizes something is wrong when he can understand what an exchange student in his class is saying (speaking Brazilian Portuguese).
The other point is later on is constantly being hunted down for being the son of Lucifer (I'm assuming at some point that he finds out the source of his strange abilities and that he never knew his father or maybe adopted). He hated it at first, but accepted it as part of his life.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do your friend have any recollection of the covers of the books?  Were these physical books or e-books?

Previously asked about here: https://www.reddit.com/r/whatsthatbook/comments/11ni4jd/ya_adult_novel_about_a_main_character_who_is_the/

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

@LogicDictates Never mind, thanks!!

The Fallen by Thomas E. Sniegoski with the first book being The Fallen and Leviathan


On his eighteenth birthday, Aaron begins to hear strange voices and is convinced he is going insane. But having moved from foster home to foster home, Aaron doesn't know whom he can trust. He wants to confide in the cute girl from class, but fears she'll confirm he's crazy.
Then a mysterious man begins following Aaron. He knows about Aaron's troubled past and his new powers. And he has a message for Aaron: As the son of a mortal and an angel, Aaron has been chosen to redeem the Fallen.
Aaron tries to dismiss the news and resists his supernatural abilities. But he must accept his newfound heritage — and quickly. For the dark powers are gaining strength, and are hell-bent on destroying him....

From the Internet Archive copy (not able to be borrowed):

They were all looking at him when it dawned. He knew what they were saying. Vilma and her friends were still speaking to one another in Portuguese — but somehow he could understand each and every word.

Found with a search for site:goodreads.com ya series son of lucifer
Not quite matching is that the fifth book, Armageddon, was published in 2013, not 2018.
